Remove FCM background handler in flutter Android
I have FCM backgroung message handling code in my Flutter(v 3.19.6) project as below:
 FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler1);

And top level function defined as below :
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler1(RemoteMessage message) async {
  //await handleRemoteMessage(message);
}

However I want to remove this function without uninstalling the app , When I try to comment both the above snippet, and just update the app (Not hot restart but flutter clean & flutter run) , I am getting runtime error
NoSuchMethodError: No top-level getter  _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler1 declared.

Is there any way to remove this vm entry without getting error.
I have checked to do this  but not allowed by flutter
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(null);


Did you mind if i ask why you want to remove it?

I do not need to add any custom logic anymore since it was causing runtime errors for some flutter plugins(Missing plugin exceptions).

So you didn't need firebase service anymore?

FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler1); Did u commented out this too? If not that is what causing the error.
NoSuchMethodError: No top-level getter  _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler1 declared.

of course I  commented FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler1);
